# jQuery table css update after append

Tags: jquery, dom, append, html-table

Here's my problem, I think code samples won't be needed:

I have an HTML table, who's first row, which contains the headings `<th>`, is used for sorting the entire table on click, and upon the data under the clicked column.

Long story short, I am manipulating the table content in such a way that I am first removing everything but the first row, and then re-populating it by my JavaScript scripting, which gives me a big compiled string that is the new HTML, which gets appended to the table.

I re-assign the event listeners and all, and that works like a charm, but the table cell coloring CSS does not update. I have the following code that sets the background of every odd row cell:

```
table tr:nth-child(2n) td:not(:first-child) {
   background-color: white !important;
}
```

Is there a way to update the table CSS coloring (the `!important` doesn't work)? I've also tried completely removing the table and re-generating it, with no luck.

Comment: Your code seems to be working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3V9L5/). Post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to use jQuery instead of CSS? It is always better to avoid "!important".

```
$("tr:even td").css("background-color", "white");
$("tr:odd td").css("background-color", "none");
$("tr:first-child td").css("background-color", "none");
```

Comment: I'm gonna flag your answer as correct because it essentially is, but the source of my problem was actually some blank <tr> elements that were generate with some buggy piece of code, once I resolved that it worked flawlessly. Thanks anyway man, I appreciate it!